# ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon20x20'"

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, xcasset

So I get the issue when uploading from Xcode 9:

```
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon20x20'"
```

I don't have the CFBundleIcons in my info.plist, and CarPlay is not selected in the AppIcon Image Assets, and I verified that every spot is filled with PNG files of the correct size.  What am I missing?

Comment: Same issue. Dit you find a solution?

Comment: Don't really know.  I cleaned, renamed stuff a few times and it went through...not sure if was server issue or some issue with something on my end.

Comment: Ok. I guess this is an Xcode issue. I did as you decribed some random cleanup (delete/create asset catalogs).